# Maven dependencies: import vs BOM

Tags: maven

I've read through https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html  and there's something I don't quite understand.

It describes 3 mechanisms of dependency management: parent pom, importing dependencies, and using BOM.

I'll state what I understand and through this will get to what I don't.

**Parent POM**

this is the simplest form. We can centralize dependency information in one POM, and then have the inheriting POMs inherit it. For example:

```
# parent
<project>
  <groupId>maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
 
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>group-c</groupId>
            <artifactId>excluded-artifact</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
 
      </dependency>
     </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>

# child
<project>
  <groupId>maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>B</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <groupId>maven</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
...
```

In this example, the child project that depends on `group-a:artifact-a` will use version 1.0 and will have the exclusions defined in the parent POM.

**Importing Dependencies**

In this option, instead of inheriting from the POM that defines the `<dependencyManagement>` section, we include it in the child's `<dependencyManagement>`. Technically, that's the whole difference:

```
# parent
<project>
  <groupId>maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
 
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>group-c</groupId>
            <artifactId>excluded-artifact</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
 
      </dependency>
     </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>

# child
<project>
  <groupId>maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>B</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  
  ...
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
     </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
...
```

So, with importing dependencies we can centralize our dependency management information in one POM, and then import it in any other POM.

**BOM**
As it is presented in the aforementioned docs page, the BOM mechanism works like this:

- BOM project - includes dependency management information of, project A and project B, and includes a module named "parent". A project of POM packaging.
- parent subproject - is a child project of the BOM project. A project of POM packaging.
- actual projects (project A and project B), which inherit from the parent subproject. These are JAR packaging projects, and they include `<dependencies>` which are included in the `<dependencyManagaement>` of the top-most BOM project.
- consuming project - in its `<dependencyManagement>`, imports the top-most BOM project, which will import all the dependency management information from the BOM project. And then, in its `<dependencies>` section, declare whatever dependencies it needs.

**The question**

So in the end, it seems that using the BOM approach and using the Import approach is pretty much the same: we have one POM project which declares dependency management information, and  other projects which import it in their dependency management section. So I don't understand - what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood how the dependencyManagement works. In dependencyManagement, you can have two kinds of entries:

1. Entries of (possible) dependencies for which you fix the versions.
2. BOMs, which are essentially lists of dependencyManagement entries, for which you use the `scope` `import`.

Entries without `scope` `import` manage that dependency, they do not import anything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you got confused just because you have missed an important note about context in [Bill of Materials (BOM) POMs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) paragraph:

> Imports are most effective when used for defining a "library" of related artifacts that are generally part of a multiproject build. It is fairly common for one project to use one or more artifacts from these libraries. However, **it has sometimes been difficult to keep the versions in the project using the artifacts in synch with the versions distributed in the library**. The pattern below illustrates how a "bill of materials" (BOM) can be created for use by other projects.

i.e. what described in documentation means the following: for some reason developer(s) made a crazy decision to use different versions for artifacts produced by multi-module project, in that case those developers, and developers who consume those artifacts, will constantly encounter difficulties caused by such weird version policy, and maven team have provided a solution/suggestion intended to minimize those difficulties.

For example, all our projects have the following structure:

```
root - inherits parent, contains parent, base and bom as <module>
 \_ bom - inherits root, enumerates all produced artifacts
 \_ parent - defines managed dependencies, does not import bom
 \_ base - inherits root, imports bom, defines plugins
 \_ module(s) - inherit base and implicitly import bom
```

at first glance it may look bizarre, but the main point is we are expecting that child projects may inherit our `parent` module and import different version of `bom`, alternatively, when `parent` and `bom` are supposed to have the same version, it could be following:

```
root - inherits parent, contains parent and bom as <module>
 \_ bom - inherits nothing, enumerates all produced artifacts
 \_ parent - defines managed dependencies, imports bom
 \_ module(s) - inherit root and implicitly import bom
```

The structure(s) above has the following "disadvantage": we need to specify module versions in two different places: in `bom` and in `version` element of particular module - we, actually, do not care much about that just because all project's modules have the same version and we use `maven-release-plugin` to manage that version.

However, if our project was containing modules with different versions that would be already a challenge, and in that case maven team suggests to turn `bom` into (grand)parent instead of importing `bom` into `parent`, which gives you following advantage: you may define those "problematic" versions in `properties` section of `bom` and reuse those property placeholders across project.

That suggestion actually contains a serious drawback: since the maven module may inherit single parent only, sooner or later you may face with the following dilemma: you either may not reuse someone's `parent pom` or you turn your `bom` into mess since it starts inheriting someone's parent pom (the most developers do mean the following under `bom`: *it should only provide dependency management for the modules managed directly by the project*)